# Generating function of $f(n) = C_n - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}f(n-k)$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions, catalan-numbers

I have combinatorially found this recurrence for a class of Dyck paths:

$$f(n) = C_n - \sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\binom{n}{k}f(n-k)$$ where $C_n$ is the $n$-th Catalan Number.

Now I want to write the generating function of $f(n)$, but I am not sure how to set up it, can someone help me please?

Comment: Start by defining $F(T) = \sum_n f(n)T^n$. Then plug in your formula for $f(n)$ and try to transform it into an identity of power series.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are [multiple types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function#Definitions) of generating functions (ordinary, exponential etc.). Your question is non-specific, so we'll go for the exponential generating function since the second part of the recurrence function looks like a binomial convolution.

So let's compute $$G(z)=\sum_{n\geq 0} \frac {f(n)} {n!}z^n$$
Then we have
$$\begin{split}
G(z)&=\left(\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{C_n}{n!}z^n\right)-\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac 1 {n!}\left(\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}{n\choose k}f(n-k)\right)z^n\\
&=e^{2z}\left( I_0(2z) - I_1(2z)\right) - \sum_{n\geq 0}\left(-\frac{f(0)}{n!}-\frac{f(n)}{n!}+\sum_{k=0}^{n}\frac{f(n-k)}{k!(n-k)!}\right)z^n&\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{(1)}\\
&=e^{2z}\left( I_0(2z) - I_1(2z)\right)+ f(0)e^z+G(z)- e^zG(z)&\,\,\,\,\,\,\text{(2)}\\
\end{split}$$
where $(1)$ uses the [generating function](https://mathworld.wolfram.com/CatalanNumber.html) for Catalan numbers, and in $(2)$ we use the formula for the product of two series ([Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product)). Here $I_0$ and $I_1$ represent the [modified Bessel functions of the first kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function#Modified_Bessel_functions:_I%CE%B1,_K%CE%B1).

Using $f(0)=C_0=1$, we obtain from $(3)$:
$$\boxed{G(z)=1+e^z\left( I_0(2z) - I_1(2z)\right)}$$

If you were after the ordinary generating function $$F(z)=\sum_{n\geq 0}f(n)z^n$$
you can obtain it, if it converges, from the exponential one [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Generating_function_transformation#OGF_%E2%9F%B7_EGF_conversion_formulas), including
$$F(z)=\int_0^{+\infty}G(zt)e^{-t}dt$$